# How to uninstall/remove Certbot Let's Encrypt from Debian 8

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt, removeall, certbot, debian-jessie

I just followed the instuctions found on : 
https://certbot.eff.org/#debianjessie-apache
to install let's encrypt certificate on my linux vps.

but unfortunately, installation did not went as I expected because :

- A. I already had an instance of apache2 installed - which conflicted
  with apache instance certbot installer installs.
- B. I have a dynamic dns I want to have as my domain name and add ssl
  for, but let's    encrypt system seems to have problem with free dns
  providers.

so I finally decided to removed certbot and instead try to install local ssl certificate I sign my self personally. I can't find direct un-installation guide for certbot. can you please help ?

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, I think I found out how to do it :

first I removed certbot using these commands :

```
sudo apt-get purge certbotapt
sudo apt-get purge python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

then I manually removed files/folders in following :

- /myuser/certbot-auto
- /myuser/.local/share/letsencrypt/
- /etc/letsencrypt/
- /var/lib/letsencrypt/
- /var/log/letsencrypt/

then I installed a new fresh instance of apache2 :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now things are back to where I was, and I can work on installing personal/local ssl for my project.

Hope this help you too ;)

Comment: you should mention that this also will remove all of your certificates ... in my case I just wanted to get rid of certbot and instead use the new certbot-auto

Comment: @Rami Ibrahim thanks for your great post that safe my day

Comment: Also remove the /etc/cron.d/certbot file to prevent failed runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove its ppa as well then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:certbot/certbot
```